# animate() doesn't work all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple slider with jQuery.

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('li').animate({'right': '400px'}, 300);
});

$('.back').on('click', function() {
    $('li').animate({'left': 0}, 300);
});
```

The problem is when I click on the bottom with the class `next`, it only slides once and the second click doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/6t1wx95f/

Comment: Because you animated only with one value. Once you animated to the right 400px it stays 400px so if you animate it again nothing happens since it's already right: 400px. Save the 400 inside a variable and add 400 everytime you scroll right and remove for left.

Comment: Change `{'right': '400px'}` to `{'right': '+=400px'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, with `$('li').animate({'left': '-=400px'}, 300);` for next.

```js
$('.next').on('click', function() {
 $('li').animate({'left': '-=400px'}, 300);
});

$('.back').on('click', function() {
 if(parseInt($('li').css('left')) <= 0){
  if(parseInt($('li').css('left')) >= -400){
   $('li').animate({'left': "0"}, 300);
  } else {
   $('li').animate({'left': '+=400px'}, 300);
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500%;
}

.slider ul {
  width: 500%;
}

.slider ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.65s;
}

.next,
.back {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="" class="active">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/a_london_cityscape_515129.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=1920x400:format=jpg/path/s86d6d6c688ca86fa/image/ie4265a3cd27b2997/version/1451246087/image.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="back">Back</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @RezaSaadati cool, also updated  so you don't go off when you click the back button.

Comment: Nice! This is how I did it (before I saw your comment): https://jsfiddle.net/6t1wx95f/7/

Answer (score -2):

Your code just adds a single left: and right: style to the element. It doesn't remove/reset these values so it only ever does anything n first click:

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('li').animate({'right': '400px'}, 300);
});

$('.back').on('click', function() {
    $('li').animate({'left': 0}, 300);
});
```

What you need to do is only animate either the left or the right (by using positive and negative values), not both, e.g.

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('li').animate({'right': '400px'}, 300);
});

$('.back').on('click', function() {
    $('li').animate({'right': 0}, 300);
});
```

Of course this won't make the thing work entirely (you'll need to increment/decrement the amount you're moving by if you want to animate each slide) but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I specifically said that in my answer. My intention was to point out where they were going wrong, not to write the entire thing for them.

Comment: How will this work if i press twice next or twice back?

Comment: Can't tell if you're being deliberately obtuse. He asked how to fix this, I answered that he needed to animate one property, not both, and implement a method to increment/decrement (which is exactly what the accepted answer does). Since when did "how do I fix this" become "you can't just tell me what I need to do, you MUST literally write the code for me otherwise it's a bad answer"?

Comment: So you don't understand what you write? If you press twice the first click will be animated but not the second one. Because once you animated the value of your property stays. So it will stay at 400px and it won't move cause there's nothing to animate between 400px and 400px. If you move left it may move if you already pressed next once, if you haven't nothing will happen cause right is already at 0 and there's nothing to animate from. See your error now? We do'nt have to redo his whole code to understand this. Check the guy that answered the actual question if you need more clarifications.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my answer: "Of course this won't make the thing work entirely (**you'll need to increment/decrement the amount you're moving by if you want to animate each slide**) but hopefully it points you in the right direction." Clearly it's you who lacks understanding.